# Cookies in Home Screen mode on ios7

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, cookies, ios7

I have a web site that my users "add to home screen" on there iPads.
Since ios7 came out i am not able to erase cookie data for this site from the device (not programatically) . clearing cookies in safari does not affect it. Event if i delete the icon on the home screen and re-add it. the session is still there. Any ideas of how to erase cookies in this case?

Comment: We encounter the same problem with our web app. After deleting the bookmark from the home screen and re-adding it, all previous cookies are still available. The only way to delete theses cookies is by doing  either via developer tools or by code when the app was started via the bookmark.

Comment: We've also tested it on iOS 6 there everything works fine, cookies got removed after deleting the home screen icon. So it really seems to be iOS 7 issue.

Answer (score 0):

I feel this is an important issue that could have security implications.

It is obvious that ios retain user data even when the add to home screen bookmark is removed from ios.

I just tried in an older version of ios (5.01 on ipad 1) and can at least confirm that on that version removing cookies in safari removes them from the home screen bookmarks as well.